# Is there a way to automate the batch export in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, batch-processing

I was able to use a shellscript to open all pdfs from a folder and save to svg like:

```
# Convert the PDF to SVG (basic conversion)
    "$INKSCAPE_PATH" --file="$pdf_file" --export-plain-svg="$SVG_DIR/$filename_no_ext/$filename_no_ext.svg"
```

But what I need to do is export individual paths as separate svg files, in a folder with the filename (the opening, saving to named folder part is working through the shell script).

Is there a way to script selecting the 'batch export' option, with 'svg' setting?

Right now I can:
Open multiple pdf files from a folder, save each one as svg in a folder created and named the filename

What I want to do:
Open multiple pdf files from a folder, save each path from that file as a separate svg in a folder created and named the filename

I can achieve this manually using the batch export dialog, but I want to iterate through many files quickly.

I had a look at the Inkscape scripting documentation but couldn't find anything that referred to scripting at this level.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Without looping through all your PDF files explicitly using a for loop, you can use this command line:

```bash
inkscape --export-type=svg *.pdf
```

This will convert all the PDF documents in the current directory to SVG format.

**Note**:

In Windows, if the asterisk `*` does not work, enter the filenames manually, e.g.:

```
inkscape --export-type=svg doc1.pdf doc2.pdf doc3.pdf
```

Comment: My bash script is already doing this.

"save each *path* (individual shapes within the pdf) from that file as a separate svg in a folder"